# What are the real perks of crafts, at endgame?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I'd like to know which are the real perks that each craft offers at endgame, in **Guild Wars 2**.

With "perk" I mean things that you **just couldn't do** if you didn't have that craft.

Anything that can be solved just buying the relative item at the trading post doesn't count, i.e. I'm searching for which hard benefits can you get **only if** you do have that craft.

I'll use World of Warcraft as an example of an answer I'd like to get:

### Enchanting

- You can **enchant your rings**. Normally you **just can't** enchant rings, so this is an exclusive benefits to enchanters. Doing so binds the ring to you, so you can't resell it: the only way to have an enchanted ring is to do it yourself. **This benefit never gets obsolete**: every time you get a better ring (by whatever means), you will be able to enchant it.
- You can **disenchant** soulbound items. Normally you have to vendor-trash them getting a small amount of gold, disenchanting instead yields materials which are (usually) quite expensive.

In case it wasn't clear, I'm using WoW as an example, I'd like to have this question answered for Guild Wars 2 instead.

I understand some crafts allow you to craft "Ascended" items, which are good but can get obsolete when you get better ones… or not? Moreover… is there anything else, hopefully?

Comment: Ascended items are the absolute strongest items in the game and will remain so for the foreseeable future. The most reliable way to get a full Ascended set is via crafting, but it's not required. It just takes significantly more effort and time to create a full Ascended set without maxing a crafting discipline.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike in WoW, crafting disciplines largely don't provide perks you can't get any other way. For the most part, weapons, armour and consumables have account-bound versions that are slightly better than what's available on the trading post. (Notably, jewelcrafting is the odd one out here.) The big exceptions are legendary components: depending on which legendary you decide to make, you'll likely need to level a crafting profession that makes useful weapons for your class and one that doesn't have a whole lot to do with your class.

For completeness' sake:

### Legendary Components

Each crafting discipline can craft account-bound Gifts at level 400, used in crafting Pact Tyria legendary weapons. Each Legendary weapon needs a weapon-specific Gift, of which only the Gift of Lightning (for Bolt) is crafted by a weapon profession. These Gifts require a material gift, either Wood, Metal or Energy, which is crafted by the discipline capable of making that weapon, either Huntsman, Weaponsmith, or Artificer, respectively. Legendaries are complicated and expensive, so once you've settled on a favourite weapon, look up the legendary for that weapon.

### Ascended Crafting

Ascended equipment are account-bound equipment items that are technically best-in-slot for a profession. They are *significantly* more expensive than exotic-tier items for a very modest increase in stats, but ascended items can hold agony resistance infusions, which let you survive higher scales of the Fractal of the Mists. Weapon and armor crafting disciplines allow you to craft ascended equipment (note: jewelcrafters *cannot* craft ascended equipment, unless Heart of Thorns changes this).

### Zephyrite Desert Recipes

The following food items are account bound, and can only be acquired by having a level 400 chef and acquiring the recipe from Zephyrites in Dry Top:

- Candy Cactus Cornbread
- Prickly Pear Sorbet
- Prickly Pear Pie
- Stuffed Nopales
- Cactus Soup
- Nopalitos Saute
- Roasted Cactus
- Black Pepper Cactus Salad
- Sweet and Spicy Beans
- Cactus Fruit Salad

### Account-bound Items

Weapon and armor disciplines can craft some max-level items with unique skins. They can also craft Celestial, Nomad's, Sinister and Zealot's stat combinations, which are all account-bound. They also craft consumable items (stones, oils and crystals), of which some account-bound variations exist.

### Daily Cooldowns

I include this because daily cooldowns are the 'perk' of many WoW crafting professions. Most disciplines get access to a few recipes that have a daily cooldown. Most of these recipes are somewhat cheaper to craft than to buy on the trading post thanks to the cooldown, with the notable exception of elonian leather and spiritwood planks. In particular, bolts of damask are significantly cheaper to craft than to buy on the TP.

Answer (score 1):

There are some [nourishments](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Nourishment) that are account-bound, and [Nomad's/Sinister](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Item_nomenclature#Triple_attribute) stats don't drop out of any ascended boxes.

**Example nourishments:**

[Bountiful Tuning Crystal](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Bountiful_Tuning_Crystal)

[Furious Tuning Crystal](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Furious_Tuning_Crystal)

The Bountiful/Furious set applies to sharpening stones and oils as well. I know there are a few foods out there that are account-bound. Note that reaching 400 in a crafting discipline is worth 40 achievement points, and 500 is worth an additional 25. Reaching 400 can cost you around 10-15g per discipline, 500 considerably more. There's a good chance we'll see more of these in HoT and beyond, so I recommend going for at least 450 if you're looking for things to do.

Comment: _"10-15g per track"_ what do you mean with "per track"?

Comment: Per discipline; I'll update it. For example, 400 in jewelcrafting even when going as fast as possible (which I suggest for the grind) is currently only 11g. http://gw2crafts.net/jewelcraft_fast.html So you not only get the benefit of 400 in a discipline, but also the achievement points.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. The ideal answer should list all such perks for every craft, though. If you don't feel like writing it no problem at all, this is already a start!